# Sphere packing question

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres

I'm a secondary school maths teacher, currently on my holidays working through some maths problems for fun. Here is one I have done, but it felt too easy, so if you could check if there's any mistakes, I'd be grateful.

Suppose there are 8 spheres, radius r. They are positioned touching each other such that the centre points of each sphere would join to make a cube.

The question is "What is the largest possible radius of a ninth sphere in the centre of this arrangement?" I think I have answered it, but I would be grateful for any input.

I don't know how to draw this digitally, so I hope my description is sufficient.

So far I have imagine the problem in 2d... four circles touching to form a square. The radius is r. The square created from the centre points will have side length 2r, therefore using pythag the diagonal is $2r\sqrt2$. Half of this will give you the distance from the centre of a circle to the centre of the arrangement: $r\sqrt2$. Therefore, subtract the initial radius, r and you have the maximum possible radius of the smaller circle: $r\sqrt2-r=r(\sqrt2 - 1)$.

Taking to 3D, the cube created by the centres 8 spheres will have a diagonal of $2r\sqrt2$ along the base and height $2r$, so again using pythag, the longest diagonal of the cube will be:

$\sqrt((2r\sqrt2)^2+(2r)^2)=\sqrt(8r^2 + 4r^2)=2r\sqrt3$

Divide this by 2 to find the distance from centre-of-sphere to centre-of-cube: $r\sqrt3$

Subtract the initial radius to find radius of smaller sphere: $r(\sqrt3 - 1)$

Comment: It's OK for me.

Comment: I just made a [simple animation](http://i.imgur.com/ahhT3k3.gif) to give a visual demonstration that for an inner sphere with radius $r(\sqrt{3}-1)$ it touches all outer spheres.

Answer (score 3):

That's correct. You could do it a bit more directly, without factors of $2$ and without iterated application of the Pythagorean theorem: The centres of the spheres are at $(\pm r,\pm r,\pm r)$. The length of each of those vectors is $\sqrt{3r^2}=\sqrt3r$, so that leaves $\sqrt3r-r=r\left(\sqrt3-1\right)$ for the radius of the inner sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ be the radius of the largest trapped sphere touching all eight spheres, each with  a radius $r$, in the arrangement. Since, cube has each edge $2r$ hence the body diagonal of the cube formed is $$=(2r)\sqrt{3}=2r\sqrt{3}$$  There are three spheres along the body diagonal of the cube hence, the body diagonal will be equal to the distance between centers of the large spheres centered at the vertices of diagonal given as  $$\text{body-diagonal of cube}=r+2a+r=2r\sqrt{3}$$ $$2a=2r\sqrt{3}-2r$$ $$\color{blue}{a=r(\sqrt{3}-1)}$$  Thus the largest sphere which can trapped at the center of cube has a radius $r(\sqrt{3}-1)$